# Cookie php in js

Tags: php, json, cookies, setcookie

If create cookie by php can't use they in js.
Create cookie:

```
function opo_setcookie( $name, $value, $expire = 0, $secure = false ) {
        if ( ! headers_sent() ) {
            setcookie( $name, $value, $expire, COOKIEPATH ? COOKIEPATH : '/', COOKIE_DOMAIN, $secure );
        } elseif ( defined( 'WP_DEBUG' ) && WP_DEBUG ) {
            headers_sent( $file, $line );
            trigger_error( "{$name} cookie cannot be set - headers already sent by {$file} on line {$line}", E_USER_NOTICE );
        }
    }
...
$cart = array("key"=>$key, "user"=> $user, "products"=> array(), "total"=> 0, "price"=>0, "lang"=>ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE);
opo_setcookie('opo_cart', addslashes( json_encode($cart) ), time()+2592000);
```

Try to get cookie:

```
function getCookie(name) {
            var nameEQ = name + "=";
            var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
            for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
                var c = ca[i];
                while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
                if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
            }
            return null;
    }
var json_str = getCookie('opo_cart');
```

But got error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token % in JSON at position 0.
Because cookie have a content "%7B%5C%22lang%5C%22%3A%5C%22en%5C%22%7D..." 
How can i fix this issue?

Comment: Which line throws this error?

Comment: var cart = JSON.parse(json_str); But decodeURI(getCookie('opo_cart')); help with that.

Comment: right, I asked because you posted code, but didn't include the line that throws the error. Next time, please include it in you excerpt and point it out.  If `decodeURI()` fixed your problem, remember to choose @Mathias Mamsch's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the decodeURI function:

```
var json_str = decodeURI(getCookie('opo_cart'));
```

See here: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_decodeuri.asp

Comment: Mathias, `unescape()` has been deprecated and should not be used in new code. there is a note on the link you posted. Use `decodeURI()` instead.